# Нету ActionBar в Android

Tags: android, actionbar

Изучаю работу с ActionBar в Android Studio. Создал новый проект, сделал все как следует, но почему то моя Activity не имеет ActionBar'a. Установил в манифесете тему AppTheme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

В общем на выходе я получаю "голую" активити без Экшн-бара. В самой студие, он тоже не отображается. В чем дело?

Comment: А в манифесте вы проставили вашу тему вашей активити?..

Comment: ActionBar считается устаревшим, попробуйте ToolBar :)

Answer (score 1):

Определитесь для начала)

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Такие данные используются для Toolbar.

Вот пример хороший для Вас https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-toolbar-example/

P.S Action Bar сейчас является устаревшим! Будьте в тренде и используйте toolbar!

Toolbar поддерживается в ОС Android с 2.2